# using activerecord with nested databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, model

I am building a rails app to store many different, user-supplied database connections and execute arbitrary sql against each of them. I am representing each database connection string as an instance of a 'connection' model and want to be able to write a method to query the database represented by each connection, ideally using the activerecord ORM. However, my code as written overwrites the database connection for the entire connections table when I use the establish_connection method in the following code. How would you advise me to change the code to query an arbitrary database, without overwriting the connection for the whole Connections table?

```
class Connection < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :host, :port, :db_name, :db_user, :db_password, :db_type

  def connect
    self.connection = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
      adapter: self.db_type,
      host: self.host,
      database: self.db_name,
      username: self.db_user,
      password: self.db_password
    )
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

A good way to do that is making a model for each database connection you need, and then make other models as subclasses of them. So, for example:

1. Define all the needed connections in database.yml (per-environment)

```
    # DB 1
    development:
      adapter: mysql2
      encoding: utf8
      database: db_1
      username: ****
      password: ****
      host: ********
      pool: 5
      ...

    # DB 2
    db2_development:
      adapter: mysql2
      encoding: utf8
      database: db_2
      username: ****
      password: ****
      host: ********
      pool: 5
      ...

    # Same for production (and/or other environments)
    production:
      ...
    db2_production:
      ...
```

1. Define a "master" model for each database, which inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`

```rb
    # DB1
    class DB1 < ActiveRecord::Base
      self.abstract_class = true
    end

    # DB2
    class DB2 < ActiveRecord::Base
      self.abstract_class = true
      establish_connection "db2_#{Rails.env}"
    end

    ...
```

1. Now define all the database-specific models as subclasses of the models defined above, in this way:

```rb
    # DB1 specific model
    class DB1_model < DB1
      # model logic here
    end

    # DB2 specific model
    class DB2_model < DB2
       # model logic here
    end

    ...
```

And you're good to go.

In this way, you can connect to N databases in different environments (usually `development`, `staging`, `preprod` and `production`, but they may be different in your case).

Also, remeber that Rails will manage a pool of SQL connections for each database.

In the example above, Rails will open a maximum of **5 connections** for each database, so total will be **10** (for a **single instance of your application**). 
If you use Phusion Passenger or Unicorn, and spawn 8 application instances, total SQL connections will be (at maximum) 10*8 = 80.

Comment: Thanks for the idea... I wound up just creating an instance method on each connection model which returns a connection using the Sequel gem . This way the databases do not need to be pre-defined in database.yml. But i'll accept your answer!

Comment: @user1609682 Thanks if you accept (I hope it helped you finding your own solution)!